# How can i give the external link to UIButton?Is it possible?

Tags: iphone

I am having the UIButton name as "Buy now".If any one touch the button,the external link should open in the safari browser.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's easy. You set the `target` and `selector` for the button, then inside the `selector`, you call safari to open your link.

*Code to call Safari:*

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)buttonPressed {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
        openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.google.co.uk"]];
}
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.google.co.uk")!)
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://www.google.co.uk")!)
```

Comment: In Swift: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)`

Answer (score 2):

Create a button, and give it a target to a selector that opens Safari with the link.

Basic example:

**Make a UIButton**

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Then the method to open the URL**

```
-(void)someMethod {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.ca"]];
}
```

Don't forget to give your button a proper frame and title, and to add it to your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buyNowButtonPressed {
    NSString *s = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com/buynowpage"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`openURL` is deprecated from iOS 10 and use following instead.

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourDomain.com"];
[application openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```